# Maven: Enforce all subdirectories are modules in aggregator pom

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-enforcer-plugin

We have [git repository](https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps) with a set of sample applications. Each sample app has its own subdirectory and its own pom.xml, but no common parent pom. The root level has an [aggregator pom](https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/blob/master/pom.xml) that *should* list all the sample apps.

```
+- sample-apps
|  +- sample-app-A
|  +- sample-app-B
|  +- etc...
```

Because each sample app has a dependency to our core product, and we want the sample apps to use our latest version, we run the `maven-versions-plugin` from the root level to keep all apps up-to-date. However, developers that add new sample apps (subfolders) forget to add them to the aggregator pom. Hence, those sample apps will become stale over time.

Is there a way for maven to enforce that all subdirectories are listed as modules in the aggregator pom? We could write a [custom enforcer rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html) for the `maven-enforcer-plugin`, but want to check for better alternatives first.

We do not want the sample apps to have a parent pom from our side, as the customer should be able to modify the sample app and inherit from his own parent.

Comment: How do you build your app? If you use CI and take the artifacts from the build server then developers will quickly notice if their new project is missing?